# Socket Hang Up while trying to hit APIs hosted on AWS via Postman

Tags: api, postman, aws-api-gateway, ready-api

I am trying to test an API hosted using AWS API Gateway and always getting following error:

```
Error: socket hang up
Request Headers
clientId: system
Authorization: //Correct Auth Token
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Accept: */*
Host: //API Host URL
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

However, when I pass in an invalid Auth Token (like TEST), I actually receive a 403 error as expected. I can also see logs in CloudWatch confirming the call reached the authorizer.
[CloudWatch Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRsEw.png)

The same API works for other people perfectly fine.
I have tried almost every resolution I found online related to this issue like I  turned off 'SSL Certificate Verification' in Postman and kept proxy settings same as my colleagues. Tried to hit the API after disconnecting VPN as well but nothing worked for me.

Could anyone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.